# Shifting vector elements to the right

Tags: java, class, arraylist, vector

I'm working on this method which should return a new Vector with elements shifted right by a given number of positions. for example:

> [1 2 3 4] 0 => [1 2 3 4]
>
> [1 2 3 4] 1 => [4 1 2 3]
>
> [1 2 3 4] 2 => [3 4 1 2]
>
> [1 2 3 4] 3 => [2 3 4 1]
>
> [1 2 3 4] 4 => [1 2 3 4]
>
> [1 2 3 4] 5 => [4 1 2 3]

my code is working on some of the inputs, only for 0, 2, and 4 while 1 and 3 aren't working.

Here's my code:

```
 public Vector shifted(int amount) {

    Vector v = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i + amount > length-1) {
             v.elements[i] = this.elements[(i+amount) % length];
        }
        else {
             v.elements[i] = this.elements[(i+ amount)];
        }
    }
    return v;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)? Javadoc says: *It is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.* Why is it raw? Generics were invented a long time ago.

Comment: It looks to me like you're actually shifting to the left instead of to the right.  Are those the results you're seeing for 1 and 3?  If that's the case, then 0, 2, and 4 would "happen" to work, because 0 and 4 don't do any shifting, and 2 would shift half the array and therefore it will look the same no matter whether you shift left or right.  I think you should try it with a pencil and paper, see exactly which indexes in `v.elements` you're assigning to which indexes in `this.elements`.  If you do that, you should be able to see how to fix it.  You're very close.

Comment: still not working, can u help me more ? please ?? i spent so much time on it

Comment: The problem you have is you are overwriting values you later need to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version that can handle any value of `amount`.

```
public static <E> Vector<E> shifted(Vector<E> input, int amount) {
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return new Vector<>();
    int shift = (amount % input.size() + input.size()) % input.size();
    if (shift == 0)
        return new Vector<>(input);
    Vector<E> v = new Vector<>(input.size());
    v.addAll(input.subList(input.size() - shift, input.size()));
    v.addAll(input.subList(0, input.size() - shift));
    return v;
}
```

**TEST**

```
Vector<Integer> input = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
for (int i = -5; i <= 5; i++)
    System.out.printf("%2d: %s%n", i, shifted(input, i));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-5: [2, 3, 4, 1]
-4: [1, 2, 3, 4]
-3: [4, 1, 2, 3]
-2: [3, 4, 1, 2]
-1: [2, 3, 4, 1]
 0: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 1: [4, 1, 2, 3]
 2: [3, 4, 1, 2]
 3: [2, 3, 4, 1]
 4: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 5: [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful to explain what's wrong with the original implementation than to just give a working solution verbatim. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Answer (score 0):

The shifting strategy you apply is incorrect. Try to think what happens when `i = 0` and `amount = 1` for a `Vector` with `length = 4`: you assign to the position `0` the value at position `1`, which is the opposite of what you want to achieve.

Here is an example of what you want to achieve in the form of a function that takes a `Vector` and a shift `amount`:

```
public static Vector rightShiftVector(Vector v, int amount){
    int s = v.size();
    int a = (amount >= 0)?amount % s : amount % s + s; // or int a = (amount % s + s) % s
    Vector result = new Vector(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        int p;
        if(i + a < s){
            p = i;
        }
        else{
            p = (i + a) % s;
        }
        result.insertElementAt(v.get(i), p);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: FYI: Solution is pretty simply. Let's say `s` is 4. For a large `amount` value of 11, you use `% s` to bring it down to 3. All good. For a large *negative* value of -9, the `% s` brings it down to -1, meaning shift 1 to the left. But 1 to the left is the same as 3 to the right, so `+ s` brings it to 3. Great. So add `if (a < 0) a += s`. *Or:* Always do `a += s`, but that makes positive go too high, so do `a %= s`, which works because `(a + s) % s == a` for positive values of `a`. All combined you simply write `a = (amount % s + s) % s` and you can handle all values of `amount`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, Andreas. I focused exclusively on the right (positive) shift. I updated the answer to handle the negative (left) shift as well.